# Why doesn't LinkedBlockingQueue use LinkedList internally?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

When reading the source code of `LinkedBlockingQueue`, I notice that it uses a linked list with `ReentrantLock`. But since Java already has an implementation called `LinkedList`, why isn't it used in `LinkedBlockingQueue` directly? Similarly, linked list is implemented again in `LinkedBlockingDeque`.

```
public class LinkedBlockingDeque<E> extends AbstractQueue<E>
    implements BlockingDeque<E>, java.io.Serializable {

    private LinkedList<E> queue;
    final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    // take the remove(Object) method as example
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        if (o == null) return false;
        fullyLock();
        try {
            queue.remove(o);
            return false;
        } finally {
            fullyUnlock();
        }
    }

    // ... the rest of the class
}
```

What isn't it implemented like the code above? What's the trade-off behind this?

Comment: Probably does not make sense to wrap/extend `LinkedList` if you have to re-implement all its methods to interact with the various locks and conditions necessary to achieve concurrency.

Comment: @Thilo Thanks for the comment. I have updated my question to demonstrate what I mean better.

Comment: And then you want to override all methods in that `queue` to talk to your `lock` (and there are two locks in the real class, plus two conditions)? So what exactly are you re-using then?

Comment: @Thilo It would 99% look like the real class. Only that it works with the `queue`  instead of the internal implemented linked list when adding/removing items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some reasons that a private linked list class is used:

1. The linked list used in `LinkedBlockingQueue` is a singly linked list.  `LinkedList` is doubly linked.  This uses more memory, and has a small performance penalty.  (This doesn't apply in the `LinkedBlockingDeque` case.)
2. `LinkedList` provides fail-fast iterators, and uses a `modCount` field to detect concurrent modification.  This must be incremented on each list operation that modifies the list.  That is a small performance penalty compared with `LinkedBlockingQueue` and `LinkedBlockingDeque` which provide weakly consistent iterators, and don't have a `modCount`.
3. `LinkedBlockingQueue` and `LinkedBlockingDeque` are *by design* weakly consistent.  If they were to use `LinkedList` under the hood, the latter's fail-fast behavior could not be hidden ... as @Holger pointed out.

Comment: Thanks, Stephen! I think you have made good points. Especially, from the iterator's perspective. I think I can find out more about the it since `LinkedBlockingQueue` supports concurrent modification via iterator.

Comment: In case of `LinkedBlockingDeque`, the nodes are doubly linked, so the memory point doesn’t apply. But the other point is much stronger, as it is more than just “a small performance penalty”, as you can’t implement weakly consistent iterators atop fail-fast iterators, and providing weakly consistent iterators is a fundamental design decision of the `java.util.concurrent` package.